# Aggregating results from SPARQL query

Tags: sparql

I'm querying a dataset of tweets:

```sql
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?tweet smo:tweeted_at ?date ;
         smo:has_hashtag ?hashtag ;
         smo:tweeted_by ?account ;
         smo:english_tweet true .
  FILTER ( ?date >= "20130722"^^xsd:date && ?date < "20130723"^^xsd:date )
}
```

If a tweet has multiple hashtags, there is one row in the result set per hashtag.  Is there any way for me to aggregate the hashtags into an array instead?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can [`GROUP BY`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#groupby) by the variables that identify the tweet and then use `GROUP_CONCAT` to concatenate the hashtags into something like an array, but it will still be a string that you'll need to parse afterward.  For instance, given data like

```
@prefix smo: <http://example.org/> .
@prefix : <http://example.org/> .

:tweet1 smo:tweeted_at "1" ;
        smo:has_hashtag "tag1", "tag2", "tag3" ;
        smo:tweeted_by "user1" ;
        smo:english_tweet true .

:tweet2 smo:tweeted_at "2" ;
        smo:has_hashtag "tag2", "tag3", "tag4" ;
        smo:tweeted_by "user2" ;
        smo:english_tweet true .
```

you can use a query like

```sql
prefix smo: <http://example.org/>

select ?tweet ?date ?account (group_concat(?hashtag) as ?hashtags) where {
  ?tweet smo:tweeted_at ?date ;
         smo:has_hashtag ?hashtag ;
         smo:tweeted_by ?account ;
         smo:english_tweet true .
}
group by ?tweet ?date ?account
```

to get results like:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| tweet      | date | account | hashtags         |
==================================================
| smo:tweet2 | "2"  | "user2" | "tag4 tag3 tag2" |
| smo:tweet1 | "1"  | "user1" | "tag3 tag2 tag1" |
--------------------------------------------------
```

You can specify the delimiter used in the group concatenation, so if there is some character that cannot appear in hashtags, you can use it as a delimiter.  For instance, supposing that `|` can't appear in hashtags, you can use:

```sql
(group_concat(?hashtag;separator="|") as ?hashtags)
```

instead and get

```
--------------------------------------------------
| tweet      | date | account | hashtags         |
==================================================
| smo:tweet2 | "2"  | "user2" | "tag4|tag3|tag2" |
| smo:tweet1 | "1"  | "user1" | "tag3|tag2|tag1" |
--------------------------------------------------
```

If you're working in a language that has some literal array syntax, you might even be able to replicate that:

```sql
(concat('[',group_concat(?hashtag;separator=","),']') as ?hashtags)
```

```
----------------------------------------------------
| tweet      | date | account | hashtags           |
====================================================
| smo:tweet2 | "2"  | "user2" | "[tag4,tag3,tag2]" |
| smo:tweet1 | "1"  | "user1" | "[tag3,tag2,tag1]" |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Now, it doesn't affect the data here, but `group_concat` will actually include duplicates in the concatenation if they're present in the data.  E.g., from the following (where I'm just providing data with `values` for the sake of the example):

```sql
prefix : <http://example.org/>

select ?tweet (concat('[',group_concat(?hashtag;separator=','),']') as ?hashtags)
where {
  values (?tweet ?hashtag) { 
    (:tweet1 "tag1") (:tweet1 "tag1") (:tweet1 "tag2") (:tweet1 "tag3")
    (:tweet2 "tag2") (:tweet2 "tag3") (:tweet2 "tag4")
  }
}
group by ?tweet
```

we get results including `[tag1,tag1,tag2,tag3]`, i.e., the duplicate value of `?hashtag` is included:

```
-------------------------------------
| tweet   | hashtags                |
=====================================
| :tweet2 | "[tag2,tag3,tag4]"      |
| :tweet1 | "[tag1,tag1,tag2,tag3]" |
-------------------------------------
```

We can avoid this by using `group_concat(distinct ?hashtag;...)`:

```sql
prefix : <http://example.org/>

select ?tweet (concat('[',group_concat(distinct ?hashtag;separator=','),']') as ?hashtags)
where {
  values (?tweet ?hashtag) { 
    (:tweet1 "tag1") (:tweet1 "tag1") (:tweet1 "tag2") (:tweet1 "tag3")
    (:tweet2 "tag2") (:tweet2 "tag3") (:tweet2 "tag4")
  }
}
group by ?tweet
```

```
--------------------------------
| tweet   | hashtags           |
================================
| :tweet2 | "[tag2,tag3,tag4]" |
| :tweet1 | "[tag1,tag2,tag3]" |
--------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I needed.  I didn't run across group_concat in any of the tutorials I found.

Comment: @BetseyBenagh Yes, I'm surprised that some of the set functions in SPARQL 1.1 don't appear a bit more prominently in the table of contents in the specification, too.

Comment: As an alternative to the solution with `GROUP_CONCAT` given here, you can also use the `SAMPLE` aggregate - which instead of concatenating all values just picks one single value.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra SAMPLE is useful when it's the right tool for the job, but I'm not really sure how it would help here, where the problem was to find a way "to aggregate the hashtags into an array".

Comment: Ah - true. I added that because I was thinking of this question as a duplicate of "how to deal with near-duplicate rows in SPARQL". Didn't read the actual question closely enough I guess.

Comment: If there are multiple properties having multiple values you want to group, make sure to use `DISTINCT` in the group_concat: 

`group_concat(DISTINCT ?hashtag)`

Comment: Just curious if that Filter( with dates) is working??!! I am trying to do something similar in Protege SPARQL Query tab but no use !!

Comment: @prathamesh I'm not sure what "that filter" means.

Comment: @prathamesh the filter inn the original question wouldn't work because the date literal is not legal. Even if it was, you would have to check whether the particular endpoint supports date ordering.

Comment: Some links i went through either had dateTime or they cast date into dateTime. So do i need to change the data property to be xsd:dateTime ? as xsd:date would not support the year() function ?!

Comment: @prathamesh all the functions are specified in the standard that's freely available online. In this case,  [year](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-year) is specified as accepting a dateTime, not a date.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor thanks for the detailed explanation!!