# How to concatenate a list of values in sparql?

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

Suppose I have a uri  http://dbpedia.org/page/Manmohan_Singh
now he has a list of years in his tag dbpprop:years.

When I write a query like

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
            PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
            PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
            PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>PREFIX category: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
            PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
            PREFIX dbprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>PREFIX grs: <http://www.georss.org/georss/>
            PREFIX category: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
            PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
            PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
            PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
            SELECT DISTINCT ?x ?name ?abs ?birthDate ?birthplace ?year ?party ?office ?wiki WHERE {
            ?x owl:sameAs? dbpedia:Manmohan_Singh.
            ?x dbpprop:name ?name.
            ?x dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?birthDate.
            ?x dbpedia-owl:birthPlace ?birthplace.
            ?x dbpprop:years ?year.
            ?x dbpprop:party ?party.
            ?x dbpedia-owl:office ?office.
            ?x foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wiki.
            ?x rdfs:comment ?abs.
            FILTER(lang(?abs) = 'en')


            }
```

I get result of each year in different row .. and hence repeating data for other collumns. Is there a way I can get it as a list in just one collumn like all the years in one collumn comma separated or smthng like that?

Similary for the prop dbpedia-owl:office

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aggregating results from SPARQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18212697/1281433).

Comment: That duplicate will show you how you can do what you want to do, but you do need to note that the year isn't the only value for which there are multiple values.  There are also various names, birthplaces, and offices.

Comment: Did you ever make any progress on this?

Answer (score 10):

This is similar to [Aggregating results from SPARQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18212697/1281433), but the problem is actually a bit more complex, because there are multiple variables that have more than one result.  `?name`, `?office`, and `?birthPlace` have the same issue.

You can work around this using `group_concat`, but you'll need to use `distinct` as well, to keep from getting, e.g., the same `?year` repeated multiple times in your concatenated string.  `group by` reduces the number of rows that you have in a solution, but in each of those rows, you have a *set* of values for the variables that you *didn't* group by.  E.g., since `?year` isn't in the `group by`, you have a *set* of values for `?year`, and you have to do something with them.  You could, e.g., `select (sample(?year) as ?aYear)` to grab just one from the set, or you could do as we've done here, and `select (group_concat(distinct ?year;separator=", ") as ?years)` to concatenate the distinct values into a string.

You'll want a query  like the following, which produces one row:

```
SELECT ?x
       (group_concat(distinct ?name;separator="; ") as ?names)
       ?abs
       ?birthDate
       (group_concat(distinct ?birthplace;separator=", ") as ?birthPlaces)
       (group_concat(distinct ?year;separator=", ") as ?years)
       ?party
       (group_concat(distinct ?office;separator=", ") as ?offices)
       ?wiki
WHERE {
  ?x owl:sameAs? dbpedia:Manmohan_Singh.
  ?x dbpprop:name ?name.
  ?x dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?birthDate.
  ?x dbpedia-owl:birthPlace ?birthplace.
  ?x dbpprop:years ?year.
  ?x dbpprop:party ?party.
  ?x dbpedia-owl:office ?office.
  ?x foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wiki.
  ?x rdfs:comment ?abs.
  FILTER(langMatches(lang(?abs),"en"))
}
group by ?x ?abs ?birthDate ?party ?wiki
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20?x%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28group_concat%28distinct%20?name;separator=%22;%20%22%29%20as%20?names%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?abs%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?birthDate%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28group_concat%28distinct%20?birthplace;separator=%22,%20%22%29%20as%20?birthPlaces%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28group_concat%28distinct%20?year;separator=%22,%20%22%29%20as%20?years%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?party%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28group_concat%28distinct%20?office;separator=%22,%20%22%29%20as%20?offices%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?wiki%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?x%20owl:sameAs?%20dbpedia:Manmohan_Singh.%0D%0A%20%20?x%20dbpprop:name%20?name.%0D%0A%20%20?x%20dbpedia-owl:birthDate%20?birthDate.%0D%0A%20%20?x%20dbpedia-owl:birthPlace%20?birthplace.%0D%0A%20%20?x%20dbpprop:years%20?year.%0D%0A%20%20?x%20dbpprop:party%20?party.%0D%0A%20%20?x%20dbpedia-owl:office%20?office.%0D%0A%20%20?x%20foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf%20?wiki.%0D%0A%20%20?x%20rdfs:comment%20?abs.%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%28langMatches%28lang%28?abs%29,%22en%22%29%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Agroup%20by%20?x%20?abs%20?birthDate%20?party%20?wiki&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Answer (score 2):

Look at `GROUP_CONCAT` but it may be easier to retrieve the data in multiple rows (you can sort to put repeats adjacent to each other) and process in code.