# group_concat with ARC2

Tags: php, rdf, sparql, semantic-web

I am trying to use the SPARQL `group_concat` aggregate with ARC2, but it appears that it is not supported.  Is there a workaround or an alternative I could use?  Given the data:

```
@prefix recipe: <url> .
@prefix myrecipe: <url> .
@prefix myfood: <url> .

myrecipe:Pizza a recipe:Recipe ;
recipe:ingredients [ a recipe:IngredientList ;
    rdf:_1 [ a recipe:Ingredient ;
        recipe:food     myfood:Chicken ;
        recipe:quantity "225g" ;
    ] ;
    rdf:_2 [ a recipe:Ingredient ;
        recipe:food     myfood:Bacon ;
        recipe:quantity "125g" ;
    ] ;
]
```

I would like my query to return one result with multiple ingredients. My current query returns a new result for each ingredient:

```
SELECT ?recipe ?food
WHERE {
        ?recipe a recipe:Recipe ; 
        recipe:ingredients ?ingredientList .
        ?ingredientList ?p ?s .
        ?s a recipe:Ingredient ;
        recipe:food ?food
}
```

When I try using the `group_concat` aggregate, the query returns `0`, and I can't find any reference to `group_concat` in the code base.

Example query using group concat:

```
SELECT ?recipe (GROUP_CONCAT(?food) as ?ing)
    WHERE {
        ?recipe a recipe:Recipe ; 
        recipe:ingredients ?ingredientList .
        ?ingredientList ?p ?s .
        ?s a recipe:Ingredient ;
        recipe:food ?food
    }
```

This is then passed to arc2 as SPARQL string. And the result returned is 0. This normally indicates an error with the query but I can't see one other than the use of group_concat

Comment: Are you using `group_concat` correctly? I see a query that _doesn't_ use `group_concat`, but what's the query with `group_concat` that you used, and what were the actual results (I'm not clear what you mean by "the query returns `0`").  Without seeing your actual query, it's hard to tell whether there's something wrong with the query or something missing from ARC2. Please note that questions about code should include the actual problematic code, and that questions asking for code should include the attempted solutions. The working query here is fine, but we need the problematic one, too.

Comment: Sorry, this was my first question so still getting to grips with the correct format for writing questions. I will edit the original question to include an example of the query I was running

Answer (score 1):

The question (at least at the time that I'm writing) doesn't include an query that uses `group_concat` or shows results, so it's not immediately clear whether the problem here is in constructing a query using `group_concat`, or getting it to work with ARC2.  However, ARC2's last release date is in 2011, whereas SPARQL 1.1 was published in 2013, so it would not be at all surprising if ARC2 does not support SPARQL 1.1.  In particular, the [version of ARC2](http://github.com/semsol/arc2/wiki) that can be downloaded from  was last edited two years ago, and the `ARC2` class has a `getVersion` function that returns `2011-12-01`. SPARQL 1.1 (which defines `group_concat`) wasn't published until 21 March 2013, so I wouldn't be surprised if ARC2 only supports the first version of SPARQL.  Additionally, the **History** section in the ARC2's readme says that

> ARC started in 2004 as a lightweight RDF system for parsing and
>   serializing RDF/XML files. It later evolved into a more complete
>   framework with storage and query functionality. By 2011, ARC2 had
>   become one of the most-installed RDF libraries. Nevertheless, active
>   code development had to be discontinued due to lack of funds and the
>   inability to efficiently implement the ever-growing stack of RDF
>   specifications.

### Cleaning up the data

Your data isn't in a completely usable format, since the `rdf:` prefix was defined.  Here's data that we can use:

```
@prefix myrecipe: <https://stackoverflow.com/q/20827591/1281433/myrecipe/> .
@prefix recipe: <https://stackoverflow.com/q/20827591/1281433/recipe/> .
@prefix myfood: <https://stackoverflow.com/q/20827591/1281433/myfood/> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

myrecipe:Pizza  a           recipe:Recipe ;
        recipe:ingredients  [ a       recipe:IngredientList ;
                              rdf:_1  [ a                recipe:Ingredient ;
                                        recipe:food      myfood:Chicken ;
                                        recipe:quantity  "225g"
                                      ] ;
                              rdf:_2  [ a                recipe:Ingredient ;
                                        recipe:food      myfood:Bacon ;
                                        recipe:quantity  "125g"
                                      ]
                            ] .
```

### A query using `group_concat`

A query like this will shows how you can use `group_concat`

```
prefix recipe: <https://stackoverflow.com/q/20827591/1281433/recipe/>
prefix myrecipe: <https://stackoverflow.com/q/20827591/1281433/myrecipe/>
prefix myfood: <https://stackoverflow.com/q/20827591/1281433/myfood/>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

select ?recipe (group_concat(?food) as ?ingredients) where {
  ?recipe a recipe:Recipe ; 
  recipe:ingredients ?ingredientList .
  ?ingredientList ?p ?s .
  ?s a recipe:Ingredient ;
     recipe:food ?food
}
group by ?recipe
```

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| recipe         | ingredients                                                                                                           |
==========================================================================================================================================
| myrecipe:Pizza | "https://stackoverflow.com/q/20827591/1281433/myfood/Bacon https://stackoverflow.com/q/20827591/1281433/myfood/Chicken" |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### More about `group_concat`

`group_concat` is described in [18.5.1.7 GroupConcat](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#defn_aggGroupConcat) from the SPARQL specification.  Some other questions and answers that include the use of `group_concat` might be of interest:

- [Aggregating results from SPARQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18212697/1281433)
- [How to concatenate a list of values in sparql?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20231536/1281433)
- [can I do this in AllegroGraph prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18917053/1281433)
- [RDF list subjects with their objects in a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18485461/1281433)
- [obtain the matrix in protege](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17924869/1281433)
- [SPARQL query to get all parent of a node](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17968971/1281433)

### Some notes about the data…

I'd point out that the triple pattern `?ingredientList ?p ?s` in the query is being used to get elements of your ingredient list.  This might get more information than what you're actually looking for, though.  If you're using a query engine that can do a bit of inference, then you might be interested in using `rdfs:member`, which is a superproperty of all the `rdf:_nnn` properties:

> #### [5.1.6 rdfs:member](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_member)
>
> `rdfs:member` is an instance of `rdf:Property` that is a super-property of
>   all the container membership properties i.e. each container membership
>   property has an `rdfs:subPropertyOf` relationship to the property
>   `rdfs:member`.

In principle, this means that you could write your query as:

```
select ?recipe (group_concat(?food) as ?ingredients) where {
  ?recipe a recipe:Recipe ; 
          recipe:ingredients [ rdfs:member [ recipe:food ?food ] ] .
}
group by ?recipe
```

Now, you'd need a query engine that can also do RDF(S) reasoning for that to work.  However, if you used an actual RDF list, you could write a query directly.  In particular, if you represented your data like this:

```
myrecipe:Pizza a recipe:Recipe ;
               recipe:ingredients ( [ a recipe:Ingredient ;
                                      recipe:food myfood:Chicken ;
                                      recipe:quantity "225g" ]
                                    [ a recipe:Ingredient ;
                                      recipe:food myfood:Bacon ;
                                      recipe:quantity "125g" ] ) .
```

and a query like this:

```
select ?recipe (group_concat(?food) as ?ingredients) where {
  ?recipe a recipe:Recipe ; 
          recipe:ingredients [ rdf:rest*/rdf:first [ recipe:food ?food ] ] .
}
group by ?recipe
```

to get the same results (in this case), but you'd be guaranteed to only get results that are actually elements of the ingredient list, and you wouldn't need to use any RDF(S) reasoning.  As a matter of opinion, I think it also makes the data and the query a little bit clearer, too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, some good points there regarding how to tidy up my data structure and query. However it hasn't resolved the issue - I excluded rdf from the prefix list as it is included in the default list declared within arc2. What seems to be the problem is that arc2 doesn't appear to support group_concat - are you aware of another way to replicate the behavior?

Comment: @palacealex Sorry for the misunderstanding;  since there was no query in the question that actually used `group_concat` or showed problematic results with it, I thought the problem was in formulating a working `group_concat` query.  (This is one of the reasons that it's so important to include attempted solutions and results (both actual and expected).)  I've commented on the question, and also made a note about ARC2's release date which is before SPARQL 1.1 (which defines `group_concat`) was published.