# how to combine two columns in sparql?

Tags: sparql, jena, protege, gruff

Hi I have the output of results like this :

```
?name ?o ?x
------------
ABCD  xyz ghh
PQR   xyz hij
```

how do I combine the columns ?o and ?x into one column called papers?
I need the output to be like this :

```
?name ?papers
--------------
ABCD  (xyz, ghh, hij)
```

Note that PQR and ABCD are replaced only by ABCD. ABCD and PQR have the same property called mbox_sha1sum

The above two were examples. I need them to be like so:

This is the current sparql query :

```
PREFIX xmlns: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 
PREFIX ontoware: <http://swrc.ontoware.org/ontology#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?name ?x ?o
WHERE { 
 ?s xmlns:mbox_sha1sum ?hash.
 ?s xmlns:made ?o.
 ?s xmlns:name ?name.
 ?o ontoware:year "2009".
 ?r xmlns:mbox_sha1sum ?hash.
 ?r xmlns:made ?x.
 ?x ontoware:year "2008".
}
```

I need to basically combine ?o and ?x into one column called ?papers
If it helps, ?s and ?r have different IRI

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aggregating results from SPARQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212697/aggregating-results-from-sparql-query)

Comment: The linked duplicate exactly answers this question.  Most of its answer describes how to do the concatenation.  The last paragraph addresses the issue of removing duplicate results by using `group_by( distinct ?var ; ... )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of grouping and aggregates like so:

```
PREFIX xmlns: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 
PREFIX ontoware: <http://swrc.ontoware.org/ontology#>
SELECT (SAMPLE(?name) AS ?GroupName) (GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(?x, ", ", ?o) ; SEPARATOR = ", ") AS ?Papers)
WHERE 
{ 
  ?s xmlns:mbox_sha1sum ?hash.
  ?s xmlns:made ?o.
  ?s xmlns:name ?name.
  ?o ontoware:year "2009".
  ?r xmlns:mbox_sha1sum ?hash.
  ?r xmlns:made ?x.
  ?x ontoware:year "2008".
} GROUP BY ?hash
```

The `GROUP BY` clause groups results together by the `?hash` variable, because you've only grouped by this variable you can't then select `?name` directly (because as you've shown there are multiple values for it) so instead you must use `SAMPLE(?name)` to give you one of the possible names (no guarantees which you get).

Then you can use the `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregate which groups togethers all values of the given expression for the group.  Since you actually have two values you need to combine you need to use the `CONCAT()` function as your expression.

Bear in mind that this won't give you precisely what you want rather you'll get something like the following:

```
?GroupName | ?Papers
--------------------------------
ABCD       | xyz, ghh, xyz, him
```

Eliminating the duplicate paper entries is potentially possible but likely to make your query much more complicated.  It may be easier to eliminate the duplicates by post-processing the `?Papers` value in Java.

Comment: Duplicates are easy to eliminate: `group_concat( distinct ?x; ...)`.

Comment: This somewhat produces the answer I'm looking for. Thankyou @RobV. It is difficult like you said to eliminate duplicates. Using distinct in group_concat produces error. I'm going to wait to see if someone gives me an answer with distinct paper listing or mark this as answer. Thanks againg =)

Comment: @PrasanaVenkatRamesh Can you clarify what kind of error you're getting?  The answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212697/aggregating-results-from-sparql-query shows how `group_by(distinct ...)` works…

Comment: @PrasanaVenkatRamesh In re-reading your question, I think I may have misread something the first time…