# Select (combine) multiple attribute values - SPARQL / RDF

Tags: rdf, sparql

I have RDF like the following:

```xml
resource: r1 <dc:title>Mathematics</dc:title><dc:title>Chemistry</dc:title><dc:size>39</dc:size>
resource:r2 <dc:title>Biology</dc:title><dc:size>42</dc:size>
```

And I have this SPARQL query to extract the values:

```sql
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> 
select distinct ?resource ?title ?size  where {
    ?resource dc:title ?title
    ?resource dc:size ?size
}
```

Results:

```
resource  title        size 
r1        Mathematics  39
r1        Chemistry    39
r2        Biology      42
```

But I want to have the following results:

```
resource  title                   size
r1        Mathematics, Chemistry  39
r2        Biology                 42
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Duplicated (and answered) at http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/27216/select-combine-multiple-attribute-values-sparql-rdf

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aggregating results from SPARQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212697/aggregating-results-from-sparql-query).  In this case, all you need is `select ?resource group_concat(?title;separator=',') { ... } group by ?resource ?size`.

Answer (score 3):

To get ?resource combined group on it.  This also allows you to use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get the titles truned into a string (the exact order will depend on evaluation).

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> 
select ?resource ?size (GROUP_CONCAT(?title) AS ?titles) where {
    ?resource dc:title ?title
    ?resource dc:size ?size
} GROUP BY ?resource ?size
```

But you may be better of with sorting and doing the fine grained processing in application code:

```
ORDER BY ?resource ?size ?title
```

instead of `GROUP BY`.