# Grouping SPARQL results for the same property?

Tags: sparql

I have the following SPARQL query:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>

SELECT ?subsidiary ?employees
WHERE {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Google> dbo:subsidiary ?subsidiary;
                                   dbo:numberOfEmployees ?employees .
}
```

And I receive the following response:

```
{
  "head": {
    "vars": [ "subsidiary" , "employees" ]
  } ,
  "results": {
    "bindings": [
      {
        "subsidiary": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/YouTube" } ,
        "employees": { "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer" , "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "53861" }
      } ,
      {
        "subsidiary": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Motorola_Mobility" } ,
        "employees": { "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer" , "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "53861" }
      } ,
      {
        "subsidiary": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Picnik" } ,
        "employees": { "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer" , "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "53861" }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The number of employees is returned multiple times because their are multiple subsidiaries associated with the queried resource. Is it possible to collapse all these subsidiaries into a list and get something more like:

```
{
  "head": {
    "vars": [ "subsidiary" , "employees" ]
  } ,
  "results": {
    "bindings": [
      {
        "subsidiary": { "type": "uri" , "value": [
             "http://dbpedia.org/resource/YouTube",
             "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Motorola_Mobility",
             "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Picnik"
          ]
        } ,
        "employees": { "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer" , "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "53861" }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really.  There isn't a an array datatype in the results format.  You can create this association by processing the results, `ORDER BY ?subsidiary ?employees` will put the rows adjacent that you want to collapse.

There is `GROUP_CONCAT` but it produces a string which is the "," separated concat of string in a GROUP. It would been parsing.  An engine may have extension aggregate functions.

Comment: @frnsys Yes, there's no way to get the value out of the SPARQL result, but you can use `group_concat` to combine the values into something that might be easier to parse afterward.  E.g., in [Aggregating results from SPARQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18212697/1281433), there's an example of  generating results like "[tag1,tag1,tag2,tag3]".