# SPARQL Query to get Movie detail

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, linkedmdb

To get movie detail from linkedmdb, I used sparql query :

```
PREFIX mdb: <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/film>

SELECT DISTINCT ?Title ?Genre ?Actor ?Country ?Director ?Year WHERE { 
?film mdb:id ?uri . 
?film dc:title ?Title . 

?film movie:genre ?filmgenre.
?filmgenre movie:film_genre_name ?Genre .

?film movie:actor ?cast .
?cast movie:actor_name ?Actor .

?film movie:country ?Ctr .
?Ctr movie:country_name ?Country .

?film dc:date ?Year .

?film movie:director ?Drc .
?Drc movie:director_name ?Director

FILTER regex(?Title, "Kingdom of Heaven")
}
```

But SPARQL results shown **Title** same as counted **Actor** . How to combine the query so that **Title** is not repeated? 
I've try using GROUP_CONCAT but not working in LinkedMDB Endpoint? 
Could someone guide me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aggregating results from SPARQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212697/aggregating-results-from-sparql-query)

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT is a SPARQL 1.1 feature, and I'm not sure that the linkedmdb endpoint supports SPARQL 1.1

Comment: Thats is problem, i think !!