# extracting a chain of instances connecting two instances through a relatio

Tags: instance, rdf, sparql, ontology, protege

I want to extract a chain of instances between two instances of my ontology by asking a SPARQL query. for example in the following figure if I want to know how A is connected to E, the result of query should be something like a list of A, B, D, F, E.

[image]

how the ontology should be designed and query should be  built?
Is it even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't too hard.  In RDF, your data can be something as simple as a direct encoding of the graph:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>

:A :connectedTo :B .
:B :connectedTo :C, :D .
:D :connectedTo :F .
:F :connectedTo :E, :G .
```

Then, using SPARQL property paths, you can find every node such that there's a path of **connectedTo** properties from **A** to it and from it to **E**, including **A** and **E** themselves:

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?mid where {
  :A :connectedTo* ?mid .
  ?mid :connectedTo* :E .
}
```

```
-------
| mid |
=======
| :D  |
| :F  |
| :B  |
| :A  |
| :E  |
-------
```

If you want to get those in order, you can additionally count how many things are between **A** and the "mid-node".  (This is described in my answer to [Is it possible to get the position of an element in an RDF Collection in SPARQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17523804/1281433))

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?mid (count(?premid) as ?i) where {
  :A :connectedTo* ?premid .
  ?premid :connectedTo* ?mid .
  ?mid :connectedTo* :E .
}
group by ?mid
```

```
-----------
| mid | i |
===========
| :D  | 3 |
| :F  | 4 |
| :E  | 5 |
| :B  | 2 |
| :A  | 1 |
-----------
```

If you actually want a single result that looks more or less like "A, B, C, D, E, F", then you adapt these queries using the techniques from my answer to [Aggregating results from SPARQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18212697/1281433), which shows how to concatenate these into a single string.

Comment: your answer was correct but I added a bit more detailed which is more complex.

Comment: I could not implement the query as you suggested. Maybe because, my connetedTo is not directed. if A is connected to B then B is connected to A too.

Comment: If the links are undirected, then you won't be able to do this with a property path;  since there's no way to specify the *length* of a property path, you can't distinguish between a path like A, B, A, C, D and the shorter version A, C, D.  As an aside, it's not a great practice to significantly change a Stack Overflow question;  it invalidates existing answers, leads to confusion, and if the question is really significantly different, it's usually worth asking as a new question.

Comment: you are right, I should not.. I will remove the new part. I can ask it as a separate question but I wonder if it is solvable or not.

Comment: @msc87 As I said, "there's no way to specify the length of a property path, you can't distinguish between a path like A, B, A, C, D and the shorter version A, C, D."  With SPARQL, you won't have a way to make sure you stay on a shortest path, just that there is *a* path.