# How to make all variables distinct?

Tags: sql, distinct, sparql

I am having a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?a ?b
WHERE { 
  ...
} ORDER BY DESC(?area)
```

but this will produce:

```
    a              b
"result1"       "item1"
"result2"       "item2"
"result3"       "item3"
"result4"       "item4"
"result4"       "item5"
```

so I am wondering, since this is for my uni, if they do not want *result4* twice, which happens because *result4* is a component of *item4* and *item5*.

So how can I tell that I want every variable to be distinct and not just the pair of a and b?

This:

`SELECT DISTINCT ?l_name DISTINCT ?region_name`

will produce an error:

> Encountered " "distinct" "DISTINCT "" at line 10, column 25. Was expecting one of: "(" ... "{" ... "from" ... "where" ... ... ...

Comment: and by doing that- which one do you want to get? item4 or item5?

Comment: "so I am wondering, since this is for my uni, if they do not want result4 twice" - You should ask whoever gave you the assignment; it may be a moot question. Also, why have you tagged this SQL? It appears to be pure SPARQL. Despite having similar syntaxes, they are very different and not compatible off the shelf.

Comment: I do not care @NirLevy. Esoteric I did but I got no answer, so I would like to present both solutions!  I removed it.

Comment: What natural language version of the query were you given to code?

Comment: What is a translation of it? You haven't given the problem statement yet.

Comment: Just to keep the question small @philipxy. Nir Levy provided a solution though. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aggregating results from SPARQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212697/aggregating-results-from-sparql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't care about column b, simply don't select it.. put in your query only a:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?a WHERE ....
```