# SPARQL query for preferred names of subclasses and their one top upper class

Tags: sparql, rdf, ontology

I'm new to SPARQL.  I would like to get the preferred name of classes and their one top level upper classes and also their synonyms in the [Radlex ontology, as hosted at BioPortal](http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/RADLEX).

And The Output I want to see:
[output](http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/RADLEX)

**Term**: equal density
**subClassOf**: density descriptor
**Synonym**: isodens, equal-density,isodense

It looks like, the code below solved my problem, but still requires some modification. Because, it brings all off the upper classes but I only want one level upper class.

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT DISTINCT  ?concept ?subClassOf
WHERE
{ GRAPH <http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/RADLEX_OWL>
  { ?term  a <http://bioontology.org/projects/ontologies/radlex/radlexOwl#radlex_metaclass> ;
        <http://bioontology.org/projects/ontologies/radlex/radlexOwl#Preferred_name>  ?concept
  }
  ?term rdfs:subClassOf ?upperClass. 
  ?upperClass <http://bioontology.org/projects/ontologies/radlex/radlexOwl#Preferred_name>  ?subClassOf.
} LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

Comment: `http://bioontology.org/projects/ontologies/radlex/radlexOwl#` is for sure **not** the URI of a class but only a namespace of some URI.

Comment: And please please please, use Markdown syntax for formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions,  learning with your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX radlex: <http://bioontology.org/projects/ontologies/radlex/radlexOwlDlComponent#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?term ?name ?synonym ?subClassOf ?subClassOf_name
FROM <http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/RID>
WHERE
{
 ?term radlex:Preferred_name ?name .
 ?term radlex:Synonym ?synonym .
 ?term rdfs:subClassOf ?subClassOf .
 ?subClassOf radlex:Preferred_name ?subClassOf_name
} LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Are you sure?!  What I see here on 2017-06-22T22:34:00-05:00 is not even valid SAPRQL.  http://www.sparql.org says:  'Lexical error at line 5, column 189.  Encountered: "\r" (13), after : "prefName"'  And that's just the first error.  I see at least one more after that.  If you can edit the query to actually run, we can talk about how to get the desired amount of class-level detail.

Comment: yes, that's much better.  I'll look that over later today.  Why don't you type out an example of the output you would like to see, with at lest a few real Radlex classes.

Comment: And The Output I wanted to see:
[output]

**Term**: equal density
**subClassOf**: density descriptor
**Synonym**: isodens, equal-density,isodense

Comment: so you want all synonyms for a given subclass concatenated on the same line?  do you know how to do aggregation of SPARQL results?  you would use group_concat in that case.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212697/aggregating-results-from-sparql-query

Comment: I was going step by step, but I could not even solve upper class problem. Thanks for the recommendation, I will study aggregation which I am not htat much familiar, yet.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like one of your main struggles is finding where to start, or how to specify the root of the Radlex subclasses.

I have no experience with Radlex, and I haven't been using Bioportal much recently.  When I opened the Radlex ontology in Protege, its class hierarchy looked reasonable to me.  But the results from the Bioportal endpoint are surprising.

For example, RID5635 "coin" is a subclass of RID5633 "personal item", and is an instance of *radlex_metaclass*, but **not** an instance of *owl:Class*, as I would expect from using OBO foundry ontologies.  It doesn't look like all of the Radlex subclasses come from the radlex_metaclass, so that makes it trickier to get all of the subclasses with a single triple pattern like

```
?s a owl:Class
```

It also doesn't look like the Bioportal endpoint supports RDFS property paths, so we can't ask for

```
?s a rdfs:subClassOf* <http://bioontology.org/projects/ontologies/radlex/radlexOwl#RID1>
```

Therefore, I can't guarantee that this query returns all of the subclasses in Radlex... just all of the immediate subclasses of radlex_metaclass

Finally, as AKSW pointed out, http://bioontology.org/projects/ontologies/radlex/radlexOwl# is the name of the ontology, not a superclass.  It doesn't have subclasses and is not a solution to the root finding problem I described at the top of this answer.

I added a named graph restriction, but that probably isn't doing anything that isn't already done by asking for http://bioontology.org/projects/ontologies/radlex/radlexOwl#radlex_metaclass instances.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  *
WHERE
  { GRAPH <http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/RADLEX_OWL>
      { ?radlexclass  a <http://bioontology.org/projects/ontologies/radlex/radlexOwl#radlex_metaclass> ;
            <http://bioontology.org/projects/ontologies/radlex/radlexOwl#Preferred_name>  ?prefName
      }
  }
```

gives results like this

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                              radlexclass                               |                              prefName                               |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| <http://bioontology.org/projects/ontologies/radlex/radlexOwl#RID19012> | "posterior root of left first sacral nerve"                         |
| <http://bioontology.org/projects/ontologies/radlex/radlexOwl#RID23593> | "nerve to third posterior cervical intertransversarius"             |
| <http://bioontology.org/projects/ontologies/radlex/radlexOwl#RID11053> | "hydrophilic wire"                                                  |
| <http://bioontology.org/projects/ontologies/radlex/radlexOwl#RID5825>  | "right"                                                             |
| <http://bioontology.org/projects/ontologies/radlex/radlexOwl#RID18947> | "posterior root of sixth cervical nerve"                            |
| <http://bioontology.org/projects/ontologies/radlex/radlexOwl#RID16116> | "set of short association fibers of telencephalon"                  |
| <http://bioontology.org/projects/ontologies/radlex/radlexOwl#RID23701> | "left third thoracic nerve"                                         |
| <http://bioontology.org/projects/ontologies/radlex/radlexOwl#RID23274> | "ascending branch of meningeal branch of right second sacral nerve" |
| <http://bioontology.org/projects/ontologies/radlex/radlexOwl#RID25244> | "right intermediomedial nucleus"                                    |
| <http://bioontology.org/projects/ontologies/radlex/radlexOwl#RID5699>  | "coalescent"                                                        |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment Mark! I just modified it and wrote the code below. It helped a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Stick with it.  Someday you will look back and ask "how did I ever manage without RDF and SPARQL?!"